# Implementing Iterable in a Java generic list when the Node generic is different than the List generic

Tags: java, generics, iterator

EDIT2:  After lots of great suggestions from you all, I've decided to just change the `D` to `T`.  The method given in the assignment did specify a `D`, but since `T` works and the overwhelming majority of you think it should be `T`, I'm just going to change it and my instructor can deal with it.  If I discover some magical workaround that fixes everything and makes `D` work, I will post it here.  Thank you all for you help!  I learned a lot today.

---

EDIT:  I would like to repeat, since I guess I wasn't clear about this at first, that I CANNOT just change it to `T next()`.  In the assignment description, it lists the method as `D next()`.  I cannot change that, it is how it was given to me.  To those who suggested I change it, thank you for your time but that is not an option.

---

I am working on an assignment where the "skeleton" of a custom List class was provided for me, and I have to write all the methods.  A `Node` class was also provided within the `List` last.  I am supposed to write an `Iterator` class in which the `next()` method is `D next() throws NoSuchElementException`.  However, since the `D` generic only appears in the `Node` class, the `Iterator` class I'm trying to write keeps telling me that `D` cannot be resolved to a type.  I've tried just writing the class within the Node class, but then I get that `The return type is incompatible with Iterator<T>.next()`.

According to the assignment, the iterator class MUST be of the type `T`, which is what the `List` is of, but the `next()` method MUST return type D.  Would someone please help me understand what I can do to get the `Iterator` class to recognize that the type `D` is the same one from the `Node` class?  I've included the skeleton code without any of the other methods implemented--the Iterator class I'm trying to write is at the bottom under "Additional classes."

How in the world can I make this `next()` method work?  Thanks to anyone who takes the time to explain this to me.

```
package list;

import java.lang.Iterable;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class List<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> {

    public class Node<D extends Comparable<D>> {
        private D data;
        private Node<D> next;
    }

    private Node head;

    public List() {
        head = null;
    }

    public boolean add(T newElt) {
        if(head == null){
            head.data = newElt;
            head.next = null;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        //Unfinished.  Iterate to check for duplicates.
    }

    public T getFirst() throws NoSuchElementException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You must write this method.");
    }

    public T get(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You must write this method.");
    }

    public T lookup(T element) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You must write this method.");
    }

    public int size() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You must write this method.");
    }

    public void delete(T element) throws NoSuchElementException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You must write this method.");
    }

    public void reset() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You must write this method.");
    }

    public String toString() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You must write this method.");
    }

    public List<T> subList(int start, int end) throws NoSuchElementException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You must write this method.");
    }

    public void removeSubList(int start, int end) throws NoSuchElementException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You must write this method.");
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You must write this method.");
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You must write this method.");
    }

    public Comparator<List<T>> lengthComparator() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You must write this method.");
    }

    public Comparator<List<T>> orderComparator() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You must write this method.");
    }


    /*
     * Additional classes
     */


    public class ListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>{

        Node current = head; 

        public boolean hasNext() {
            if(head.next == null){
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public D next() throws NoSuchElementException{
            return null;
        }

        public void remove() {

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: use `T` instead of `D`, as your node actually T

Comment: Take a look at the `Node` class and how it defines its own generic type parameter and uses it.  The `ListIterator` class should do the same.

Comment: I think you need to write the `add` method and `toString` method and then write some test code to make sure they work. The write `get` and `lookup` and then `delete`. You will learn enough doing this that the iterator will be much easier. Write them one at a time and write some test code to run and verify they are working.

Comment: Use back quotes (`) to format inline code (on a standard American keyboard it's the key immediately underneath the Esc key).

Comment: Thank you StormHawke.

Lee Meador:  I need the iterator class to write those methods, as I need to traverse through the list and add them in the correct spot.  This list is supposed to be sorted.

Comment: Unless you either change the `D` in the `ListIterator` class to a `T` (or vice versa), then __nothing else you can do will make the code compilable__ (except commenting out the entire class). Without that change, the code will consistently cause compilation errors, even if every other part of the program is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Where you have:

```
private Node head;
```

you should instead have:

```
private Node<T> head;
```

The same thing applies to `Node current = head;` in the iterator.

Remember, the `Node` class you defined is a generic -- you should always specify its generic parameters, just as you should always use `List<Foo>` instead of just the raw `List`. Since `T extends Comparable<T>`, the compiler will know that it satisfies `Node`'s requirement that `D extends Comparable<D>`.

---

Unrelated: You should consider making `Node` a `private static class` instead of a `public class`. The `private` is good for encapsulation, since users of your `List` shouldn't care about its internal linked-list implementation. The `static` is good good practice unless the inner class actually needs to access fields in its enclosing class (that is, unless `Node` needs to access fields in `List`, which it doesn't in the code you have).

Comment: Thank you for your point on defining Node.  I will change that.

The Node class was not written by me, and I'm not supposed to edit the code that was already written.  I think this must have been done for testing purposed.

Answer (score 0):

you iterator class should look like :

```
public class ListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>{

    Node<T> current = head; 

    public boolean hasNext() {
        if(current.next == null){ // check if next node exists
            return false; // doesn't exist
        }
        return true; // exists
    }

    public D next() throws NoSuchElementException{
        if (current.next == null){ // check if there is next node
            throw new NoSuchElementException(); // if not throw new exception
        }
        current = current.next; // changing to next node
        return current.data; // provide the data in next node
    }

    public void remove() {
        // since Node class save the reference to next Node and doesn't for previous, 
        // removing objects it quite difficult, because it will break the lis
    }

    }
```

Comment: You need to use `Node<T> current = head;` and then `public T next()`

Comment: Unless you are defining the `ListIterator` as an inner class of `list`, you need to define a constructor for the `ListIterator`.

Comment: Regrettably, it must be public D next(), because that's how it's written in the assignment description.  Thank you for your other suggestions though, I will look at those.

Comment: @AlanaEmrysHulse no, that makes no sense, because `D` has no meaning in a class that has no `D` type parameter. If you make the type parameter `D` as well, it will work, but that is just stupid, and almost certainly a typo from whoever created the assignment.

Comment: @AJMansfield Exactly, that's what I thought.   But the same pdf has been used to explain this assignment for several semesters.  You'd think they would have caught a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The `Node` class will contain one `D` which is the same as a `T` because you will create the nodes with code like this:

```
Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>();
newNode.data = newElt.
```

That's where the `D` and the `T` become equal.

Answer (score 0):

Like Eugen Halca said, you need to define an iterator class; I would recommend doing it slightly differently: instead of defining `Node` and `ListIterator` as inner classes of the list class, I would define them as independent top-level classes. I'm really not sure what it is you get from using inner classes other than a big headache over namespace issues, so I would recommend just defining them independently (except for anonymous inner classes, those are OK).

So the file `ListIterator.java` should contain:

```
protected class ListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    Node<T> last, current;

    public ListIterator(Node start) {
        current = start;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if(current.next == null) return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public D next() throws NoSuchElementException{
        if (current.next == null) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        last = current;
        current = current.next;
        return last.data; //otherwise it will skip the first item!
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() throws IllegalStateException {
        if(last == null) throw new IllegalStateException();
        current = last.next = current.next;
        //doing it this way, the remove method is very simple
    }

}
```

Note the use of annotations to help protect you against problems that can arise if no parent class or interface actually defines a method you believe is being overridden. You also need to add one to the `iterator` method in your `List` class, because that method is (supposedly) inherited from the `Iterable` interface.

The file `Node.java` should contain:

```
protected class Node<T> {
    private T data;
    private Node<T> next;
}
```

Note that the type parameter for the `Node` class should **NOT** be specified `Comparable`, because there are no methods in the `Node` class that invoke any methods specified in the `Comparable` interface. Any class that will be using the comparability of the elements stored in the nodes will already know about the comparability of it, but forcing them to be comparable means you can't use that class for other things you might like to be able to.

Please, don't pick up bad habits like these; if I ever found a book with code in it like the code you gave (except if used as an example of almost-but-not-quite-acceptable code), I would throw it out. If an instructor were insisting that I do it this way, I would drop the class, since clearly the instructor has no idea what they are talking about.

Comment: The Node class was written for me by the instructor as part of the skeleton and cannot be edited aside from adding certain parameters to change the list to a doubly-linked list or something similar.
I am also not allowed to add any top-level classes.  I basically have to work with the provided skeleton, and that is all I have.  I have to take this class to complete my major, so regrettably I can't drop it either.
I'll just keep working at it and hopefully the higher level classes will be of better quality.
Thank you very much for your time!  I greatly appreciate your help :)

Comment: @AlanaEmrysHulse By the way, when you are doing the parts where you have to create new instances of the `Node` class, you should use the diamond operator `new Node<>()`, rather than spelling it out as `new Node<T>()`. (unless you are required to use java 1.6 or earlier, which may unfortunately be the case for you, going on the description of the other aspects of the course)

Comment: @AlanaEmrysHulse Another thing; nearly all the bad programming instructors I have had didn't even notice when I made this kind of correction to the assignment code. I am pretty sure yours wouldn't, either, especially since one of the mistakes makes the code non-compilable, yet other students have been managing to do the assignment despite. (Clearly, they corrected it for themselves, at least.)